# Position relative or absolute and text align left

Tags: html, css

I have seen many answers on this but doesn't seem to work for me. I have code like this which creates two boxes red colored:

```css
.redboxes-horz {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.redbox-horz-lg {
    width: 76.05%;
    background: rgba(200, 16, 46, 1);
    padding: 17px 20px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: calc(23.95%);
    position: relative;
    height: auto !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.redbox-horz-sm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: rgba(200, 16, 46, 1);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -22px;
    left: calc(23.95% - 22px);
}

.redbox-horz-lg h1 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="redboxes-horz">
    <div class="redbox-horz-sm"></div>
    <div class="redbox-horz-lg">
        <h1>Structural Discovery Branding Standards Heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks right now

[image]

The issue is that I want my heading to be left aligned. For some reason when I make the display as inline-block the whole CSS gets disturbed and stops working.

Comment: It's not center aligned at all. It's left aligned of that div.

Comment: Yes it not perfectly center aligned but somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I'm getting this https://codepen.io/njmsaikat/full/PoOZgjv

only spaces it's taking is just padding and as usual.

Comment: Your code in the question does not match your screenshot, as you can see from the Stack Snippet I just created in an edit. Please edit your question to include the missing styles so that it matches your problem statement and image.

Answer (score 0):

For `.redbox-horz-lg` try using `align-content: justify;` or `align-content: left;`. If not try `align-items`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: The only other change I can make to get the result you want is changing `left: calc(23.95%);` to `left: 50px` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes, you are expect like this?:

```css
.redboxes-horz {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: white;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.redbox-horz-lg {
  width: 76.05%;
  background: rgba(200, 16, 46, 1);
  padding: 27px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.redbox-horz-sm {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: rgba(200, 16, 46, 1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -22px;
  left: calc(23.95% - 22px);
}

.redbox-horz-lg h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="redboxes-horz">
  <div class="redbox-horz-sm"></div>
  <div class="redbox-horz-lg">
    <h1>Structural Discovery Branding Standards Heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted the text to be left-aligned, not the whole div.

Comment: @Ahsan I edited my answer, please try that. I have given a certain height to `.redboxes-horz`.

Answer (score 0):

Use left:0; for the class .redbox-horz-lg in css.

```
.redbox-horz-lg {
left:0;
}
```

```css
.redboxes-horz {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.redbox-horz-lg {
    width: 76.05%;
    background: rgba(200, 16, 46, 1);
    padding: 17px 20px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left:0px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto !important;
    
}

.redbox-horz-sm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: rgba(200, 16, 46, 1);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -22px;
    left: calc(23.95% - 22px);
}

.redbox-horz-lg h1 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="redboxes-horz">
                            <div class="redbox-horz-sm"></div>
                            <div class="redbox-horz-lg">
                                <h1>Structural Discovery Branding Standards Heading</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```